# Windows XP, have to use ctrl+alt+delete to log on as local administrator

Tags: windows, windows-xp, login

I have a weird issue, a user was logging into a laptop using the local admin account which was working fine. I had to create another account on the system, which was also an admin account. When this happened, the '`administrator`' account disappeared from the `choose an account to login with` screen.

A quick workaround is available, if the user presses <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>, it brings you to the screen where you can type in the username and password, so by manually typing 'administrator' one can log in.

Normally this would be easily fixed. I figured out the admin account had somehow been disabled from the local system, but I checked all settings and it is setup fine.

The laptop is not part of a domain, so I used the management console to delete the new account and all that succeeded in doing was making the `choose an account to log in with` screen display no accounts to choose.

So far I see nothing else to fix it.  The option to change the default logon screen to style where you type the username and password also seems to be missing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Default behaviour for XP is to hide the administrator account if a second account exists. MS reccommends using limited user accounts for daily use. Have you tried this HOWTO?

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/05/07/unhide-the-administrator-account-in-windows-xp/